# How to run karate tests from project jar?

Tags: karate

I am using karate 0.9.2 with gradle. My project requires to have all karate tests inside src/main/java. So I configured the gradle dependency as ‘compile’ instead of ‘testCompile’ and also modified the sourceSets to point to main instead of test. When I ran my runner class with above configuration I got empty test suite message.

build.gradle snippet:

```
compile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:0.9.3'
compile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.3'

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/main/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have is to run the karate tests from the deployable project jar. Please point me the resources I can refer to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not something we directly support but teams have done this in Spring Boot etc. It should be possible, see if this thread helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/520

Also you may not need JUnit also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/427

And see the sample project in this ticket as an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/529

EDIT - in 1.0 onwards we hope that class-loading from spring-boot JAR files is more reliable: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/751