# How to distribute Karate testing framework?

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

**Problem statement:** Every service has a separate repository. what is the best way to use a common framework across several service repositories?

We are trying to create an API test automation framework using "Karate".
Here we want to create a framework(Which can be distributed(example:jar)) such that it can be used across all of the microservice project repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the creator of Karate, I strongly recommend you don't do this. In the long term this makes all your projects depend on one common framework - and you should try to reduce the creation of "home grown" frameworks. Especially for a testing framework, you should try not to force teams to depend on an additional library which you need to maintain and version-control. Re-use can cause more harm than good especially in the context of testing, see [this article at the Google Testing Blog](https://testing.googleblog.com/2019/12/testing-on-toilet-tests-too-dry-make.html).

That said, since Karate can [read files from the `classpath:`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files) you can "ship" a JAR file with common Java classes and even feature or JS files that all your projects can inherit from or "re use". In fact the [`karate-base.js`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-basejs) has been designed to solve for common bootstrap logic or variables / parameters being supplied from a JAR file.

Short Answer: use normal Java techniques (Maven / Gradle) to create a re-usable JAR file, e.g. put your feature files and JS files in `src/main/*` and not `src/test/*`. There are multiple ways to use resources (Java, `*.feature`, JS) from a JAR file. It is up to you how to structure your Maven (or Gradle) projects to make this happen.

EDIT: for those looking for how to create a "runnable" JAR, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553194/143475

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment on my question. I am able to use java classes and java functions in feature file, but I am not getting how do I call/use the functions defined in a javascript file(which are from a jar file) in the feature file? and also how to use a properties file or any other files.

Comment: @tejeshkumarreddynagireddy ask another question with a specific example if needed 1) in karate you always use JS via a feature file: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file 2) in karate `karate-config.js` replaces all the mess of properties files: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs