# Unable to call utilities in another module of karate maven project

Tags: karate

I am getting following exception when trying to call feature file of another module from different module with logs as,
`org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class utils.Utils is not allowed or does not exist.`

Following is the file which I am trying to run as,
https://github.com/bipin-k/karate-automation/blob/master/sample-automation/src/main/java/sample.feature

https://github.com/bipin-k/karate-automation

[karate error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLJ0I.png)

Comment: sorry, your project is too complicated for me to understand so I'm giving up. if you can, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this answer for hints on how to handle re-use across Java modules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58339662/143475

Recommendation is to avoid it as far as possible. And things like `call read('../../../../core-utilities/src/main/java/java-functions-calls.feature')` lead to un-maintainable tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Most likely the problem is because in the project where you make the `call` - the `utils.Utils` class is simply *not* on the Java "classpath". You should probably take the help of someone who knows Java well, or stick to a simpler "single module" Java project.