# Accessing java script files from outside the classpath in a karate-config.js file

Tags: karate

I have a util file that I need to access called util.js from karate-config.js and would like it available for both modules to use.

```
util.js
module1
-- src
--- test 
--- java 
---- karate-config.js
module2
-- src
--- test 
--- java 
---- karate-config.js
```

I have tried karate.call('classpath:util.js') which results in a
FileNotFoundException. I have tried an absolute path and it does not work.

Any other suggested approaches I could try ?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.  You'll need to provide more information for anyone to be able to help

Comment: Sorry . I just edited it. Hopefully it makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use something like `karate.call('file:./test.js')` or something similar. This is not really recommended, because the chances of `test.js` being available when you check-out from version-control are low.

I strongly recommend moving `test.js` to lie side-by-side with `karate-config.js` and then things will work using `classpath:test.js` as you expect.

Refer the docs for more: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#naming-conventions

Comment: I have added some details to the original description. What I need is a shared util file across 2 modules. Is that possible ?

Comment: @KarenD'souza yes, if you know what you are doing, use the `file:` prefix as I already said (relative paths like `../../foo` should also work) or see this answer for a more advanced approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58339662/143475