# Karate not able to find feature file inside the jar app

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

I am trying to execute some feature file using karate runner(feature file is bundled with application jar file) from REST controller class call. In service class I am using karate runner to run the tests.

```
public Results executeTest(String featureFile, List<String> featureTags) {
   return Runner.path(featureFile).tags(featureTags).parallel(10);
}
```

Resource file exist under `resources/abc.feature` inside the jar file, so I am providing `featureFile="classpath:abc.feature"`, also I have tried with `featureFile="abc.feature"` or `featureFile="./abc.feature"`, but Karate is not able to find the feature file. Is there a way to pass the file path of feature file which is inside the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using the `classpath:` prefix: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#reading-files

For example:

```
Runner.path("classpath:abc.feature").parallel(1);
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58339662/143475

Comment: It works while I am running the application from eclipse but when I am running the spring-boot jar, It is not finding the file. Ideally It should have been worked! By the way, how karate is loading the file? using `getresourceasstream` or anything else?