Karate - when running tests with the karate.jar, `karate.callSingle('classpath:xxx.feature')` in karate-config.js fails with not found: xxx.feature
I put together a reproducible example of karate.callSingle() erroring out when it's run with the karate.jar at git repo. It is also the same repo that I post about down below. Want to see if I'm using the karate jar incorrectly.
My project has the following structure:
 |-src
 | |-test
 | | |-resources
 | | | |-karate-config.js
 | | | |-tests
 | | | | |-test1.feature
 | | | |-auth
 | | | | |-oauth2.feature
 | | |-java
 | | | |-AllTest.java
 |-pom.xml

karate-config.js has the following content:
function fn() {
    karate.configure('retry', { interval: 0 });

    let accessToken = '';

    if (karate.env === 'prod') {
        // Happy path
        accessToken = 'mock oauth2 access token';
    }
    if (karate.env !== 'prod') {
        // ERROR: this doesn't work when running as standalone jar
        const result = karate.callSingle('classpath:auth/oauth2.feature', {});
        accessToken = result.access_token;
    }

    return {
        access_token: accessToken,
    };
}

And under resources, the auth/oauth2.feature (pretty much just returns a mock access-token):
@ignore
Feature: oauth2

Scenario: Obtain oauth2 token
  * url 'https://example.com'
  * method get
  * status 200

  # Mock data here. In real use case, use the access token from response
  * def access_token = 'mock oauth2 access token'

And finally, a simple tests/test1.feature also under resources dir:
Feature: Access token

Scenario: Validate access token
  # consume access token obtained in config
  * url 'https://example.com'
  * method get
  * status 200

  * match access_token == 'mock oauth2 access token'

Now, when I go under src/test/resources and run java -jar /tmp/karate.jar ., I get the following error:
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: auth/oauth2.feature
- com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.getResource(ResourceUtils.java:126)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.toResource(ScenarioFileReader.java:129)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:64)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.read(ScenarioBridge.java:731)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.callSingle(ScenarioBridge.java:229)
- <js>.fn(Unnamed:12)

I tried a bunch of different command line options, like setting the --workdir=$(pwd), --configdir=$(pwd), and also -cp /tmp/karate.jar:. (I think -cp won't work anyways when using java -jar), but to no avail. I got the same error message.
Is this the intended behavior that karate.callSingle('classpath:<something>) will not work at all when running via the standalone karate.jar?
My understanding from the karate docs was that, karate.callSingle('classpath:...') should work (and it does work) when it's invoked via maven. So, what do I need to do to get the standalone jar to work as well?
Any help is appreciated.

After digging into the implementation of karate ResourceUtils, I found the issue has to do with the classpath: prefix. Prebuilt jars can't resolve classpath:-prefixed files that are located external to the jar.
For now, I'm going with this workaround

yes, files have to be part of the jar or somehow on the classpath, also refer this answer. do you mind if I close this question as a duplicate of this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58339662/143475

@peter thank you for confirming. And sure, feel free to close this as duplicate. I'll look into the methods mentioned in that answer and see if I can get a cleaner build.

thanks ! also see this part of the documentation, you can customize the classpath even for the standalone JAR: https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-netty/#custom-classpath

@peter perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. It's much cleaner than the jar uf workaround that I was thinking of. Thanks again!
