# How can I run Karate TestRunner with java main method for JUnit5

Tags: java, karate, junit5

I'm trying to run karate test using the TestRunner main method for JUnit 5 but could not run.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore.main(TestRunner.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(TestRunner.class, 5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}
```

JUnit version 4.13
.E
Time: 0.015
There was 1 failure:

1. initializationError(com.walmart.drs.services.sds.TestRunner)
   org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.walmart.drs.services.sds.TestRunner':

1. No runnable methods
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:525)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:102)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:84)
   at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.(JUnit4.java:23)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
   at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:50)
   at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:125)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:111)
   at org.junit.runners.Suite.(Suite.java:81)
   at org.junit.runner.Computer$2.(Computer.java:33)
   at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
   at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:77)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:116)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
   at com.walmart.drs.services.sds.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:14)
   FAILURES!!!
   Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1

Comment: I even want to call the Runner inside main method, but it seems like it is not supporting and also I do not found any reason why it is not suported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do and please assume it is not supported.

Please use the `Runner` class as described in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-5-parallel-execution

Actually the `Runner` does not depends on JUnit at all - so if you want to put this code inside a `main()` method, you can do that, and omit the `assert()` if needed.

```
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TestParallel {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:animals").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

}
```

And if you are not already, please migrate to 1.0.0 - we won't be supporting old versions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: thanks for quick response. I want to build a jar of karate tests and then I want to run through command ```java -jar integration-test.jar``` or ```java TestRunner```. If I use one of these command then it give an error that main method not found.

Comment: Any suggestion or any other approach that how I can run tests using a jar?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanMuhammadSaleem please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553194/143475

Comment: I read the link you mentioned. So you don't support this feature. But same code works when I use Test annotation from Junit 4. and It is failing when I use Test annotation from JUnit 5.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanMuhammadSaleem then it is a JUnit question, so re-frame it and ask a new question on stack-overflow if needed

Comment: ok thanks for your cooperation.